# JavaScript delete element function and continue numbering

Tags: javascript, html, dom, button

In the example below I have a script with the button that adds textareas one below another as question fields. At the same time, I want to add the `delete()` button, that will delete the specific textarea (whole input) and reset the numbering to continue normally (1,2,3...).

To be clear, if I add 3 textareas, and delete second, I will have 2 textareas numbered 1,2.

What is the solution, and how my delete() function should look like?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/26aYj/)

**index.html**

```
ADD NEW QUESTIONS HERE:
<input type="submit" value="ADD NEW" onClick="add();"><br/><br/>

<div id="new"></div><br/>
```

**script.js**

```
var n = 1;
function add() {
  var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textarea.name = "question" + n;
  textarea.rows = 4;
  textarea.cols = 50;

  var div = document.createElement("div");    
  div.innerHTML = n + ". Question: <br />" + textarea.outerHTML + "<br />" + '<input type="submit" value="DELETE" onClick="delete();"><br/><br/>';

  document.getElementById("new").appendChild(div);
  n++;
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about a solution at all?

Comment: Try delete elements function.

Comment: Of course, but I didn't put my code here, because, it isn' tworking at all - I am a beginner, but I assume this is the short piece of code that I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure JS solution:

working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/ckELj/)

```
function add() {
  var nums= document.getElementsByClassName('no')
  var n = nums.length+1;
  var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textarea.name = "question" + n;
  textarea.rows = 4;
  textarea.cols = 50;
  var div = document.createElement("div");    
  div.innerHTML = "<span class='no'>"+n+"</span> . Question: <br />" + textarea.outerHTML + "<br />" + '<input type="submit" value="DELETE" onClick="delete1(this);"><br/><br/>';
  document.getElementById("new").appendChild(div);
}

function delete1(el){
 var div= el.parentNode;
 div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
 var nums= document.getElementsByClassName('no');

for(var i=0; i<nums.length;i++){
    nums[i].innerHTML = i+1;
 }
}
```

i've wrapped the question number inside a span having `class='no`, every time we add a new questions, the question number will be the number of such existing spans+1.
when ever we delete a question, remaining spans are numbered from 1 starting from the top.

Answer (score 3):

I would propose to use HTML features too for this task. You can benefit from using `UL` element and `list-style-type: decimal` property for numbering:

```
<ul id="new"></ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

And delete function (better not to call it `delete` it's a language keyword) would be just simple `removeChild`:

```
function deleteQuestion(obj) {
    obj.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(obj.parentNode);
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="submit" value="DELETE" onClick="deleteQuestion(this);">
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/26aYj/1/

Comment: damn! i wasted my time manually doing this! thanks for the info :)